# `TypeError: Failed to fetch` for valid URL that works in the browser

Tags: firebase, fetch

I think this might be an easy one.

I'm trying to use the fetch api to get files from Firebase Storage. The promise rejects with `TypeError: Failed to fetch`, but the same URL works when I load it from my browser. I get the same result for both audio and image files.

I don't think it can be a CORs error, because I'm successfully loading the image files on multiple domains (using `img` html tag).

example:

```
fetch('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gigameshmusic.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fpreviews%2FOne%20More%20Time%20%5Bpreview%5D.mp3?alt=media&token=28ccfa80-6245-4201-9449-aeb8bed15c25&_gl=1*1esa73i*_ga*MjAyNzc2ODY2My4xNjg0MTI5MjE1*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4NjYxNDg3My4zOC4xLjE2ODY2MTQ5MTYuMC4wLjA.')
```

It seems something unique to using the fetch api with Firebase Storage. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Chrome wasn't showing me all the error info for some reason. It indeed was because I didn't have [cors set up on firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).